# Multiply a number of Textboxes by Labels and Pass the value to another Label

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am building an application and it basically has many textboxes and labels. The labels and textboxes are tagged in sequential numbers for example txtBox1, txtBox2 etc...same for the labels. I have written code for this and it seems a bit long winded because there is a lot of repetition and I want to avoid that. I wanted to know if there is a way I can use a loop and substitute the last numbers on the names to populate the labels? See my code below.

```
'Metric Conversion of weight
lblwkg21.Text = Format(21 / 3.281 * SCAFF_TUBE_MET * txtST21.Text, "###,##0.00")
lblwkg20.Text = Format(20 / 3.281 * SCAFF_TUBE_MET * txtST20.Text, "###,##0.00")
lblwkg19.Text = Format(19 / 3.281 * SCAFF_TUBE_MET * txtST19.Text, "###,##0.00")
lblwkg18.Text = Format(18 / 3.281 * SCAFF_TUBE_MET * txtST18.Text, "###,##0.00")
lblwkg17.Text = Format(17 / 3.281 * SCAFF_TUBE_MET * txtST17.Text, "###,##0.00")
lblwkg16.Text = Format(16 / 3.281 * SCAFF_TUBE_MET * txtST16.Text, "###,##0.00")
```

For the above I would like to substitute for example in a loop from 21 to 16 so VB can loop through the textboxes and labels.

Comment: Have you though about using a DataGridView and calculated Columns?

Comment: No I haven't, but it sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a `New List(of Tuple)` and initialized it with a `From` clause. The elements of the list are created with `Tuple.Create` passing the controls Label and matching TextBox.

I get the number by converting the substring to an `Integer`. I used the start index as 5 because my control name has five characters before the number. `Label1` You would have 6 characters before the numbers start. `lblwkg21` Remember the index of the first character is 0. This should work for weeks with one digit or more.

`tup.Item1` refers to the first portion or the Tuple, the Label, and `tup.Item2` refers to the second portion, the TextBox.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ctrlList As New List(Of Tuple(Of Label, TextBox)) From {Tuple.Create(Label1, TextBox1), Tuple.Create(Label2, TextBox2)}
    Dim multiplier As Double = 1 / 3.281 * SCAFF_TUBE_MET
    For Each tup In ctrlList
        tup.Item1.Text = (CInt(tup.Item1.Name.Substring(5)) * multiplier * CDbl(tup.Item2.Text)).ToString("###,##0.00")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try it out and get back to you.

Comment: I tried this and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.